Clarification on step in proof equating 2 line segments

AMC 12A Problem 16, 2012 -
Circle $C_1$ has its center $O$ lying on circle $C_2$. The two circlesmeet at $X$ and $Y$. Point $Z$ in the exterior of $C_1$ lies on circle
$C_2$ and $XZ=13$, $OZ=11$, and $YZ=7$. What is the radius of circle
$C_1$?

https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2012_AMC_12A_Problems/Problem_16?srsltid=AfmBOorV3amBQ5uzZr_iTSclJ5wUAKKgn68CETngITON0DyoAWH2ZpKc
I was able to solve this with only law of cosines using the fact that $XO = OY$  and thus $\angle{AZO} = \angle{OZY}$
Then from cosine law in $\triangle{AZO}$ and  $\triangle{OZY}$, I computed $r = OX =  \sqrt{30}$

The question I have is concerning an alternate proof given on AoPS, which is listed as solution 6:

Use the diagram above. Notice that $\angle YZO=\angle XZO$ as they
subtend arcs of the same length. Let $A$ be the point of intersection
of $C_1$ and $XZ$. We now have $AZ=YZ=7$ and $XA=6$. Consider the
power of point $Z$ with respect to Circle $O,$ we have $13\cdot 7 =
> (11 + r)(11 - r) = 11^2 - r^2,$ which gives $r=\boxed{\sqrt{30}}.$

The question being how does $\angle YZO=\angle XZO$ imply that  $AZ=YZ=7$?

If $W$ is the point that $\overline{AY}$ and $\overline{OZ}$ intersect, then those two angles being equal implies $\Delta AWZ$ and $\Delta YWZ$ are similar, but they also share a side length…

How do we know $ΔAWZ$ and $ΔYWZ$ are similar.  We only know they share a side and an angle right

$\overline{AY}$ and $\overline{OZ}$ are perpendicular.

Yes, that would imply the similarity, but how do you know they are perpendicular, we don't know that W is the midpoint of AY.

The arcs $AW$ and $YW$ subtending the same length implies $\angle AOZ=\angle YOZ$ since $O$ is the center of the circle. I guess this also implies the aforementioned triangles are similar, but these angles being equal also implies the lines are perpendicular

How is AW an arc. It is not at all necessary that W lies on the circle. Please refer to the edited image in the question. Also, how are you so certain that they subtend the same length.

Sorry, I meant by $W$ the point where $\overline{OZ}$ intersects the circle. The solution you cited is where the assertion about subtending the same length comes from.

Let $B'$ be the perpendicular projection of point $O$ on line $ZY$. We have $ZOB\cong ZOB'$ (ASA) and $OBA\cong OB'Y$ (RHS). Hence:
$$
AZ=BZ-BA=B'Z-B'Y=YZ.
$$

Thanks. Would this normally be considered a trivial step, and I was too stupid to understand it? Or should it have been included in the AoPS answer, in which case I could edit it over there as well to prevent future confusion.

I think it's obvious enough not to be mentioned in those answers. Also because the question asks for a numeric answer, not for a complete proof. @Illusioner_
